# General form for $2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)((a+b)t^2+a-b)} \mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I encountered this integral in physics-- $$2\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)((a+b)t^2+a-b)} \mathrm dt$$

I know for certain that $a,b \in \mathbb{R^+}$, $a>b$.

$a$ and $b$ are independent variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A=a+b$ and $B=a-b$.  Convert this into a complex integral and integrate over a semicircle in the uhp. The poles that lie in the contour are $\displaystyle z={\rm{i}}$ and $z={\rm{i}}\sqrt{B/A}$. As the radius $\to \infty$ the integral over the arc vanishes, hence for $\color\red{a>b>0}$,
\begin{align}
I
&=\oint_\Gamma\frac{1-z^2}{(1+z^2)(Az^2+B)}{\rm{d}}z\\
&=2\pi{\rm{i}}\left[\lim_{z\to {\rm{i}}}\frac{1-z^2}{(z+i)(Az^2+B)}+\lim_{z\to {\rm{i}}\sqrt{B/A}}\frac{1-z^2}{A(1+z^2)(z+i\sqrt{B/A})}\right]\\
&=\pi\left[\frac{2}{B-A}+\frac{1+B/A}{A(1-B/A)\sqrt{B/A}}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi\left(\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}\right)^2}{2b\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

As already answered by Troy Woo, partial fraction decomposition gives $$ \dfrac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)\Big((a+b)t^2+(a-b)\Big)}=\frac{a}{b\Big( (a+b) t^2+(a-b)\Big)}-\frac{1}{b \left(t^2+1\right)}$$ which lead to simple integrals. As a result $$\int \dfrac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)\Big((a+b)t^2+(a-b)\Big)} dt= \frac{a \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t \sqrt{a+b}}{\sqrt{a-b}}\right)}{b \sqrt{a-b}
   \sqrt{a+b}}-\frac{\tan ^{-1}(t)}{b}$$ and, then for the integral $$I=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)((a+b)t^2+a-b)} dt=\frac{i \pi  \left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{b-a} \sqrt{a+b}}+i\right)}{b}$$ provided that $$\Im\left(\frac{\sqrt{b-a}}{\sqrt{a+b}}\right)>0$$ So, for real $a$ and $b$, provided that $a \gt b$, $$I=\frac{\pi  \left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}-1\right)}{b}$$

Answer (score 2):

Apply partial fractional decomposition, and then you will easily solve it with basic techniques.

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{-(\pi+(i \pi c_1))}{\frac {\sqrt{c_2-c_1}} {\sqrt{c_1+c_2}}}{c_2}$$ for $\Im(\frac{\sqrt{c_2-c_1}}{\sqrt{c_1+c_2}})<0$

I got to this with Mathematica.

Comment: This is not LaTeX as it stands. Please reformat.